# Записать dataset в XML

Tags: xml, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, использую метод `WriteXml()`. На форме выбираю разные данные и по нажатию кнопки записываю. Сколько раз нажму - столько данных запишет.

Если я заново открою форму и запишу новые данные, то всё перезапишется.

Как можно сделать, чтобы новые данные просто добавлялись в файл, а не перезаписывали старые.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сперва считать из файла ранее записанные данные (методом `ReadXml`) в дополнительный `DataSet`. Потом объединить новые данные со старыми методом [`Merge`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/System.Data.DataSet.Merge%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). После чего сохраняем в файл.